# cookie is not setting in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a application like insorts app in which first two pages have normal ui elements & third fragment has webview. The second fragment is the default fragment of viewpager.

just after login I redirect to second fragment & now if I swipe left to webview, the cookie is not getting set & webview is asking for login. But if I remove the app from background & open again & reach to second fragment & I do the same it works fine.

my code:

```
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(HomeScreen.context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
cookieManager.setCookie(baseUrl, cookie);
cookieSyncManager.sync();

webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
webview.loadUrl(my url);
```